# Showing that a set $S \subset [a,b]$ is dense.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[a,b] \to [0,\infty)$ be a Riemann integrable function such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx =0$. Then how does one show that the set $S= \{x \in [a,b] \ : \ f(x)=0\}$ is dense in $[a,b]$.

- To show $S$ is dense in $[a,b]$ i have to show that given $x,y\in[a,b]$  there is a $z \in S$ such that $x<z<y$.

Not sure how to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried with contradiction? Can you have that for all $z \in (x,y)$, $z \notin S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ is not dense in $[a,b]$  then there exists an open set $U\subseteq [a,b]$ such that $U\cap S=\emptyset$.

Let $(c-\delta,c+\delta )\subseteq U$.

Then $0=\int_{[a,b]} f\ge \int _{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}f> 0$ (since $f\ge 0$)
which is false.

Comment: ... so $0\ge 0$ is false... :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you find $x,y\in[a,b]$, $x \neq y$ and $[x,y]\cap S =\emptyset$. Then $f(s)>0 \ \forall s\in [x,y]$.
Say $c_0=\inf_{s\in[x,y]} f(s)$, then $c_0>0$.
Therefore $\int_a^bf(s)ds\ge\int_x^y f(s)ds \ge c_0 (y-x)>0.$

Comment: Why $c_0>0$? It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: Because $[x,y]\cap S =\emptyset$ and $f(s)> 0 \ \forall s\in[x,y]\cap S$

Comment: I mean $f(s)>0$ only implies $\inf f(S)\ge 0$, which is not sufficient. Unless you make some continuity assumptions...

Comment: $S\cap [x,y]$ is compact set, so, if I am not wrong, $\min$ and $\inf$ coincide.
Therefore $\min_{[x,y]\cap S} f >0$

Comment: What you would need is $f((a,b))$ to be compact, but yoou don't know if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Uhm you are right @mathbeing

Comment: After more thinking, $f$ is Riemann integrable implies $f$ is continuous almost everywhere (Lebesgue criteria for Riemann integrability). So we can take a point of continuity in $s_0 \in [a,b]$ to make $f(s)>\epsilon>0$ on a neighborhood of $s_0$. But as I said, it is not obvious.

Comment: I misread the hypotheses, I was suppose $f$ continuos when I wrote the answer so $c_0>0$ seemed obvious to me. 
With your comment I think the proof is rigorous. Thanks @Momo

Comment: @Momo I was thinking of that too, but we need to assume also that $f$ is bounded, right?

Comment: f is bounded if it is Riemann integrable. In fact Lebesgue criteria says that it is Riemann integrable iff bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: @Momo Sure, I might be too used to Lebesgue integration..

Comment: This proof is wrong as it stands. @Momo, you probably should answer with your observation about a.e. continuity.

Comment: I put the proof together for posterity :) Feel free to vote the answer to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was asked, I will put together the proof:

$f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ $\iff$ f is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ (Lebesgue's criterion of Riemann integrability)

Suppose $S$ is not dense in $[a,b]$. There exists $a\leq c<d\leq b$ such that $[c,d] \cap S=\emptyset$, which is $f(x)>0$ on $[c,d]$

$f$ cannot be discontinuous on the whole $(c,d)$, because this set has (Lebesgue) measure $>0$, so there is a point of continuity $x_0\in(c,d)$

From the continuity property and for an arbitrary $\epsilon\in(0,f(x_0))$, we can find a $\delta>0$ with $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]\subset (c,d)\subset[a,b]$ such that $f(x)\geq\epsilon>0$ for all $x\in[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$

Thus:

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \ge \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0-\delta}f(x)dx\ge2\delta\epsilon>0$

contradiction with $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$

Answer (score 0):

Prove the *contrapositive*: if $S$ is not dense in $[a,b]$, then $\;\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x>0$.